# incrond running but not executing command under CentOS 6.4

Tags: bash, inotify, centos6, selinux

I have installed incron from the EPEL repository (before you ask; YES, I also tried downloading the source and compiling locally; same results) and am attempting to set up a process on my CentOS 6.4 (final) virtual box that I have successfully prototyped on my local Ubunto 12.04 machine:

Some information up front:

- SELinux is set PERMISSIVE
- I have added my script(s) and called executables to all with NOPASSWD using `visudo` to get around some permissions issues...

If I invoke my script from the command line with `sudo /path/to/my/script.sh arguments` it works like a charm.

`sudo service incrond status` verifies that incrond is running. root and myusername are added to `/etc/incron.allow`, `/etc/incron.deny` is empty.

My incrotab for root is:

```
/path/to/dropfolder/ IN_CLOSE_WRITE sudo /path/to/my/script.sh $@/$#
```

Events in `/path/to/dropfolder/` result in exactly NOTHING happening. No logs are generated, no messages, no actions occur on the files in the folder.

So I have researched: it was suggested that `cron` runs in a minimal environment and that to execute complex commands/scripts you may have to execute your `.bashrc` and/or export your PATH at the beginning of the cron command.

**Note:** I can find no documentation supporting that `incron` also runs in a minimal environment, but as my google-fu (and bing-fu!) failed to result in any helpful results related directly to `incron` I figured WTH, I'll try that!

**Edit:** Documentation indicates that `incron` run from system tables or root takes env from its host enviroment, therefore only `incron` executed by non-root users should require any sort of env or PATH fiddling

So… incrontab for root:

```
/path/to/dropfolder IN_CLOSE_WRITE . /home/myusername/.bashrc; export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin; sudo /path/to/my/script.sh $@/$#"
```

No dice… tried `&&` instead of `;` = no dice. If you can think of a variation on the above I've probably tried it…

So, lets try a little `restorecond -R /usr/sbin/incrond /etc/incron*` action!
Huh, no change there either.
`service incrond stop` followed by `service incrond start` and then `service incrond restart` … nope, nope, and nope.

Drastic measures: `yum remove incron` and `yum install incron`, `chkconfig incrond on` and then for good measure a `sudo reboot`!

Nothing.

I don't even get anything from `/tmp/ IN_ALL_EVENTS echo boo>>/home/myusername/boofile.txt`, hence my inability to even do an `env>>envfile.txt` to check whether `incron` is running in a sparse environment… (see above note)

And yet: `service incrond status` yields `incrond (pid  xxxx) is running...`

What am I missing? It has to be big and obvious and I hope someone can make me feel like an idiot in short order!

further examination of `/var/log/cron` yields results like this: `Aug 14 15:05:30 hostname incrond[1584]: (root) CMD (sudo /path/to/DropFolder/script/subfolder/script-Beta-1.sh /home/username/DropFolder/testfile.file)` -yes I made sure my script was executable..

so incrond is indeed attempting to do SOMETHING, but I get no output anywhere... even a simple `echo > /dev/pts/0` produces nada results.

- thanks for fixing my crap formatting job

Comment: Thanks, I had a different issue but I found it by doing: `tail -f /var/log/cron | grep --line-buffered incron` and noticed that each command is executed twice, but that's another issue.. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, here's the answer:

Despite all documentation I can find declaring it to be the contrary, `incrond` under CentOS 6.4 runs in a sparse environment and behaves as `cron`. this is NOT the case under Ubuntu, where incron inherits its environment from root for system tables and root tables and only user tables run in a sparse environment. This of course means that if you're calling a script (I am) the script needs to build it's environment and every thing must have a full path. **EVERYTHING**. (well, except for shell builtins :p)

numerous Google and and Bing and Stack Overflow and Server Fault searches all told me that `cron` operates this way, but they all also seemed to indicate that `incron` operates as described in the documentation, which it DOES under Ubuntu...

Bottom line, it works now, yay!

- I guess this just goes to show: when in doubt define the environment and use full paths... er, actually, just do that all time and save yourself a headache.

(this does not address my problem with applying a SELinux security policy for `incron`, but I'll worry about that later, in another post...)

Comment: thank you sir for sharing this one. Had the same issue, and it worked once I declared all the paths explicitly.

Comment: I had big trouble running multiple commands in the same command line, so I ended up putting everything into a bash script and then execute that from incron instead.